# CSS3 Rails and Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem with CSS3 code and heroku. I am currently hosting my website temporary on heroku, and this piece of code doesn't not seem to work:

```
#my_footer
{
    margin-top:170px;
    background-color:rgba(17,142,36,0.3); /* added this because of the backgroud */
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
```

especially this line of code: `background-color:rgba(17,142,36,0.3);` 
the strange part is that it works on my localhost, but not on heroku! and i am using the same browser!

btw I have this in my config/environments/production.rb

```
...
  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true #changed to true!
...
```

otherwise heroku returns me an error, and does not display the page if it is 'false'
I am using twitter bootstrap btw!

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error that happens during the deploy ? What is the type of your file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try compile localy and then try to push it,

from heroku

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If you use the twitter bootstrap gem I think it should be grouped in assets

```
group :assets do
  gem 'twitter ...'
end
```